# Why is it giving me the error "method ArrayList.add(String) is not applicable"?

Tags: java, arrays, list, project, message

Whenever I run this driver class in Java, it gives me this message:

> method `java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.String)` is not applicable.

I am doing an `ArrayList`, and here is my code:

```
 ArrayList<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

 categories.add( new Education() );
 categories.add( new Games() ) ;
 categories.add( new  Medical() ) ;
```

It is giving me an error at the `.add`.

I wrote out `Education`, `Games`, `Medical` like that because I have separate classes that I want it to connect to. Those separate classes, such as `Education`, have a list of apps, such as educational apps.

Comment: What do you think `ArrayList<String>` means? Have you learned about generics?

Comment: If you have declared your `ArrayList` to contain `String`s, you have to add `String`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

`ArrayList<String>` means you want an array-backed list that can hold `String` objects. This restricts the `add` method to only accept strings. The mistake you are making is that you are passing other non-`String` objects into the `add` method.

**Bad Answer 1:**

The easy way out is to change it to `ArrayList<Object>`, but this defeats the purpose of generics. The good thing is, you can now pass any object to the `add` method. The bad thing is, you can now pass *any* object to the `add` method.

**Bad Answer 2:**

You can create three `ArrayList` objects instead:

```
ArrayList<Education> eduCategories [...]
ArrayList<Games> gameCategories [...]
ArrayList<Medical> medCategories [...]
```

But this is also bad, because now you have three lists.

**Good Answer:**

You only need one list. For this, you have to create a proper hierarchy:

1. Create an abstract class called `Category`:

   ```
   abstract class Category
   ```
2. Create three classes `Education`, `Games` and `Medical`, all extending `Category`:

   ```
   class Education extends Category
   class Games extends Category
   class Medical extends Category
   ```

Then you can create your list as:

```
ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

categories.add( new Education() );
categories.add( new Games() ) ;
categories.add( new Medical() ) ;
```

In this case, you're restricting the `add` method to accept only a `Category` object. Since `Education`, `Games` and `Medical` are all (by extension) `Category` objects, they will be accepted. But the following will fail:

```
categories.add( "some string" ); //compilation error: String is not a Category
```

So now we are able to take full advantage of generics (compile-time type protection) while allowing different sub-classes to be accepted by the same list.

Comment: Okay, i see what you are saying, but where do I place the ArrayList<Category> ? In a driver class or the abstract?

Comment: Change your original code `ArrayList<String>` to `ArrayList<Category>` (wherever that is - you should know).

Comment: Ok, so I've been doing this and it worked, but now how do I save the app names. For example, where do I save the Educational apps? i was thinking about making an array list in the class "Education," but I don't know if that's right.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. 1. You can make an `ArrayList<String>` in your `Category` class. This will be accessible via all its sub-classes. 2. If you have an `App` class to represent an app, you can make an `ArrayList<App>` in your `Category` class. The idea is the same, except now you have `App` objects in each category (proper OO), whereas in (1), you just have strings representing names of the apps.

Answer (score 1):

You declare an arraylist of type String but then try to fill it with other non-string entities.

<s>You may instead want to create an arraylist of objects:</s>

```
ArrayList<Object> categories = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And then you can interact with the classes by referencing them from the arraylist.

My response is incorrect, this wouldn't function correctly. If all you need is categories and values, you can just use:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> categories = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

Then you can create some more ArrayLists for each category, populate the categories, then add them to the top level ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> medical = new ArrayList<String>();
medical.add("one");
medical.add("two");
medical.add("etc");
categories.add(medical);
```

Comment: While this would solve the problem of `.add()` failing, it's a terrible answer that will only lead to further confusion for the OP. And the edit is just as bad.

Comment: @BrianRoach How would you suggest I approach the task then?

Comment: By not giving bad advice. The OP's *real* problem is far too broad to answer here unless you want to take guesses at his classes and what they are supposed to be doing, then offer a complete redesign. Could be as simple as them really only needing a `Map<String, List<String>>` period to represent their data, or maybe they really need a proper class hierarchy where the top level is `Category`

Comment: Basically, what @ADTC just did.

Comment: OP here. Sorry for all the confusion; I should have been more clear. I am making an interface that essentially recommends mobile apps to a user. The first question asks them what device they have(Android or iOS). Then, let's say they choose Android, it will list them 10 categories found on the app store(business, medicine...etc) and in my original post I listed three. Then, if they choose something like Educational, it will list the top eight apps in Educational for Android. An easy project in essence, but I am getting confused.

Comment: @lightandlight suggested a two-dimensional array. how would I go about doing this? I also forget to add that I have two abstract classes, each has the ten classes(for ten categories) connected to them( public Education extends Apps). Then I have a driver, and an interface. I was tring to list the eight app names in each class, and then have an arraylist in the driver, which was my original post, that saves the category names, to later list to the user.

Comment: You are better off using the OO approach suggested by ADTC considering how you have structured your program

Comment: Thanks @lightandlight. Your approach is more suited for situations where just Strings need to be stored in a list. Using a full OO approach in such situations would be an overkill and would introduce inflexibility `=)`

Comment: @lightandlight Ok, so I've been doing this and it worked, but now how do I save the app names. For example, where do I save the Educational apps? i was thinking about making an array list in the class "Education," but I don't know if that's right

Comment: @user3191697 Well in keeping with the object oriented approach you could include an arraylist of strings in the Category class and methods to add/remove/retrieve strings. This would then be inherited by all its subclasses